# Grouping by Assigned to in SharePoint view

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm trying to create a view which groups all tasks according to "Assigned To" Column. I know there already is a view in SharePoint what does this but my issue is that my "Assigned To" column is allowed multiple values.

Is there any way to workaround this?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom C# web part to display the data grouped by individual users in a multiple user assigned-to. Other than that, there isn't a way to elegantly group by users when multiple users are allowed in assigned-to.